# How To Display Notifications From the Administrator on the Home Screen

Tags: home-page-layout

I would like to show notification on HOME page. I am thinking to create a custom object and host it on HOME page. I am looking for some alternatives or best approach to cater the requirement.
As of now the notification will be posted by ADMIN users.

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking is correct direction I will advice you to have a look [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.notif_builder.htm&type=5) "Notification Builder" will help you to show the notification which is the out of the box way to show notifications ( Chatter mention, Task etc) which is shown under the BELL icon and visible from every page. Any unread message comes as red-circle with number of unread message

[image]

1. Create a Custom Object
2. Give Object Permission and Field level security
3. Use notification builder to publish your notification from a process/Flow.

See this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEBHn0-eXJ8)